# How to find default kotlin compiler argument values?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinc

Currently I use a bunch of compiler flags in my gradle build file. I'm sure some of these are defaults that I would prefer not to specify explicitly (and thereby have them updated automatically as the compiler is updated).

But I cannot find any documentation on default values for various compiler options. How to determine them?

```
kotlinOptions {
    languageVersion = "1.5"
    apiVersion = "1.5"
    jvmTarget = '11'
    useIR = true
}
```

Comment: see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#attributes-common-for-jvm-js-and-js-dce

Comment: starting from Kotlin 1.5, IR-based backend for the Kotlin/JVM compiler is enabled by default, so there is no `useIR` option anymore; it's replaced with `useOldBackend`

Comment: Most are default except `jvmTarget`.

Comment: thank you for the correct answer (first comment) and additional clarification @Михаил Нафталь